# How to smoothly move the stroke from one position in Keyframe A to another in Keyframe B in 2D animation?

Tags: animation, 2d

I'm trying Blender 2D animation. I have a keyframed stroke in a certain position. In *Object Mode*, if I create another keyframe a few frames further and transform (translate, rotate, scale) the entire stroke, Blender automatically and smoothly interpolates between the two keyframes as expected.

But once I'm in *Edit Mode* and create another keyframe, which transforms part of my stroke, and I press play, the stroke abruptly jumps from the first keyframe to the second without inbetweening.

Why is Blender not smoothly interpolating between these two keyframes in *Edit Mode*?

Answer (score 0):

In object mode there is an automatic interpolation between keyframes that can be set (linear, stepped or Bezier with ease in and ease out, which is default).

In edit mode every single point of a strroke has to be calculated.

This can be performed drawing two keyframes: put the timeline cursor between the two, go to Grease pencil Menu > Interpolate sequence (or press Ctrl Shift E).

Set the parameters of the interpolation in the black panel on bottom left (press F9 to make it appear if not present).

The interpolation works very well if the structure of the drawings remains the same (so the 2nd keyframe has been edited in edit mode or sculpt mode, without adding or removing points).

If not, some unpredictable interpolations can happen.

[image]